# how to run a c program using a java program using JNI

Tags: java, c, dll, header, java-native-interface

i have browsed all over the internet and right now i stuck in generating the Shared library.
First Java File :

```
import java.io.*;
public class JavaToC {

public native void helloC();

static {
    System.loadLibrary("HelloWorld");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JavaToC().helloC();
}}
```

After Compiling the above java program i also made the header file using :

```
javah JavaToC
```

Now i wrote my simple C program :(HelloWorld.c)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <JavaToC.h>
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JavaToC_helloC(JNIEnv *env, jobject javaobj) 
{
printf("Hello World: From C");
return;
}
```

Now i wanted to create a native Shared Library but here where i stuck , i used

```
gcc HelloWorld.C -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include -IC:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include\win3 -shared -o HelloWorld.dll
```

But after putting these command in windows ,it returns error :

```
gcc: error: Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include: No such file or directory
gcc: error: Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include\win3: No such file or directory
```

I'm unable to clear it out ! :((

Comment: Obviously you need to escape or quote the spaces in your arguments. If you don't, anything after the space is treated as another argument. Hence the error.

Comment: could you please show me sir ? DarkFalcon

Answer (score 0):

You can use SWIG (see http://www.swig.org/) for generating Java API wrapper on top of your C code.
You have to write a swig interface file only which is used by swig to generate appropriate .java files for different classes and their contained methods.

In your current approach, one problem you are facing is because you need to put quotes around Program Files to escape the space.

Comment: but even after putting the quotes it comes with invalid argument :((
Could you please specify where to put the quotes actually i'm a naive in programing

Comment: Put quotes around the entire path "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include"

Comment: yeah i put, but again it throws errors :
**HelloWorld.c:3:21: fatal error: JavaToC.h: no such file or directory **

Comment: This is a different problem now. Not the original problem "gcc: error: Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include: No such file or directory". Where is the file located actually? Is its path included?

Comment: yeah i have already specified this path in OS Path ! what shall i do now ?
[link](http://javapapers.com/core-java/how-to-call-a-c-program-from-java/)
I've doing using this tutorial link mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

`gcc -c -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include" -I"/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/include/linux" HelloJNI.c`

In Ubuntu, file name is `HelloJNI.c`
and `-I/usr/lib/jvm......` is the path where the file is kept.